# Export Sql data to Excel , Store long int to string in excel

Tags: c#, sql, for-loop, export-to-excel

I have this working C# code to export Sql Server data to excel. The problem is one column contains long `int` and it appears in excel as 6.71524E+11. So I understand that we have to convert it as string in excel.

How to implement that in my code? Examples would be appreciated.

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {

            string conString = "Data Source=DELL\\SQLSERVER1;Trusted_Connection=True;DATABASE=Camo;CONNECTION RESET=FALSE";

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString);
            sqlCon.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select TOP 10000 LocalSKU,ItemName, QOH,Price,Discontinued,Barcode,Integer2,Integer3,SalePrice,SaleOn,Price2 from dbo.Inventory", sqlCon);


            System.Data.DataTable dtMainSQLData = new System.Data.DataTable();

            da.Fill(dtMainSQLData);
            DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns;

            // Export Data into EXCEL Sheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            int i = 1;

            int j = 1;
            //header row
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtMainSQLData.Columns)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = col.ColumnName;
                j++;

            }

            i++;

            //data rows
            foreach (DataRow row in dtMainSQLData.Rows)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count + 1; k++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[i, k] = row[k - 1].ToString();
                }
                i++;

            }

            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:/Users/Administrator.CAMO/Downloads/FtpFilesStorage/Export/Sheet1.xlsx");

            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();

            Console.WriteLine(".xlsx file Exported succssessfully.");
        }
```

Comment: @ConradFrix Can you help on this..

Answer (score 0):

This method work for exporting to an Excel file.

```
private void ExportToExcel(DataTable Tbl, string ExcelFilePath = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (Tbl == null || Tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        //Excel.Workbook ExcelBookServices = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

        // single worksheet
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        // column headings
        for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = Tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }

        // rows
        for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // to do: format datetime values before printing
            for (int j = 0; j < Tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Tbl.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }

        workSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        //workSheet.Columns.Style = "Output";
        //Excel.Range cell = ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[Tbl.Rows.Count, Tbl.Columns.Count]);

        // check fielpath
        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
        {
            try
            {
                workSheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                excelApp.Quit();
                //File Saved Message
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath Message
            }
        }
        else // no filepath is given
        {
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error in creating the Excel file
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but I have already this program working correctly. I just want to add apostrophe "'" like mother's in one of the columns..

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to

```
            int i = 1;
            int j = 1;
            //header row
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtMainSQLData.Columns)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = col.ColumnName;
                j++;

                ExcelApp.Rows.AutoFit();
                ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
            }

            i++;
            Console.Write("Progressing......65%  \n  Wait for around 8 minutes \r");
            //data rows
            foreach (DataRow row in dtMainSQLData.Rows)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count + 1; k++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[i, k] = "'" + row[k - 1].ToString();

                }
                i++;

                ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                ExcelApp.Rows.AutoFit();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

use the property NumberFormat:
    MyWorkBook.NumberFormat = "@";

Comment: your current answer contains less information than it should be. please try to elaborate so that your answer could be more understandable and helpful.